# Transferring data from one workbook to another with specific condition

Tags: vba, excel

I have two workbooks .One is called Target workbook while the another called source workbook.

Target workbook has all the project ID and some of the project ID would appear more than once. in Source workbook it is empty as no data is entered yet.

I would need a code where it will allow me to go through all the rows of the Project ID in the target workbook which i would want to transfer the information to the source workbook.

For example, I would project ID "10000327" appeared more than once in the target workbook and i need to transfer all the rows that has "10000327" on the project ID.

For now, I am able to only find the matching project ID only once and does not allow me to look through all the rows until empty row is found and the code will stop searching. Thus, it does not allow me to capture more than one project id that contain "10000327" in the target workbook. This could only runs when both the workbook has project ID but i would like a code where it only focuses on target workbook project ID and transfer it to the source workbook instead of doing a match between target and source workbooks.

This is the code that i have so far:

```
Sub AAB()
    Dim sWS As Worksheet, tWS As Worksheet
    Dim pidCol As Long, pidRow As Long, pidStr As String, rw As Long

    Set tWS = Workbooks("Target.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sWS = Workbooks("Source.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet2")

    With tWS
        With .Cells(2, 1).CurrentRegion
            pidCol = 1
            pidStr = "10000327"  '.Cells(rw, pidCol).Value
            If CBool(Application.CountIf(.Columns(1), pidStr)) Then
                rw = Application.Match(pidStr, .Columns(1), 0)
                With .Cells(rw, 2).Resize(1, .Columns.Count - 1)
                    If CBool(Application.CountIf(sWS.Columns(1), pidStr)) Then
                        pidRow = Application.Match(pidStr, sWS.Columns(1), 0)
                        .Copy Destination:=tWS.Cells(pidRow, 2)
                    End If
                End With
            End If
        End With
    End With

    Set sWS = Nothing
    Set tWS = Nothing
End Sub
```

I hope anyone could assist me as I have been stuck in doing this for almost 2 weeks. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't your way a bit overcomplicated. Maybe I misunderstood something, but if you want to find a project id and copy the line to the different workbook you can loop through the lines and copy lines that have the right project id:

```
For LineNo = 2 To Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    If Range("A" & LineNo).Value = pidStr Then
        sWS.Rows(LineNo & ":" & LineNo).Copy Destination:=tWS.Rows(tWS.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1 & ":" & tWS.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1)
    End If
Next LineNo
```

or you can filter the data sheet and copy out only the remaining lines:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=pidStr
Rows("2:" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=tWS.Rows(tWS.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1 & ":" & tWS.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1)
```